# How to visualize connections between survey participants

Tags: data-visualization, survey, social-network

I have the dataset from survey with participants IDs and IDs of another participant (or participants) that first participant knows, just like this:

| Participant ID | Knows participant |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 353 |
| 111 | **777** |
| 111 | **112** |
| 111 | 249 |
| 112 | 143 |
| 112 | 144 |
| 113 | **111** |
| 113 | 244 |
| 114 | NaN |
| 115 | **113** |
| ... | ... |
| 777 | **111** |
| 777 | 398 |
| 777 | **114** |
| 778 | NaN |
| 779 | **112** |
| 3499 | NaN |

As you can see, some participants do not know any other participants (but it does not mean, that other participant also does not know him/her), however, some participants know 1, 2, 3 or even more other participants (and again some participants might does not not her/him and vise versa).

So is it possible to build and visualize all possible connections between each participant (personal acquaintance, acquaintance through another participant and so on)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! People like to use "Force-Directed Graph Visualizations", which basically makes a figure trying to get nodes that are "friends" close in the visualization. You in particular have a directed graph (cause A can be B's friend but not vice versa); this makes things tough to Google because of the "Directed" in the title of the visualization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing

Comment: This sounds just like a plot of a network, albeit with some directionality. I'm not sure what else is being sought here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a Network Navigator Chart from Power BI library. I can not say that I've achieved all goals that I wanted to, however, this chart is pretty easy to use and it is also possible to upgrade the chart by transform your data a little using DAX or Python (to color the first customer in the chain or to filter only chains with >1 connection).